# How to keep updates (diffs) of some entity in the database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

What is the best way to keep updates (diffs) of the some entity in the database? Here, at StackOverflow, we can edit questions and answers. And then we can look at any revision of the question or answer we want. For example:  [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60174/revisions) of some random question. Maybe someone knows how it realized in StackOverflow?

To be clear in my case I have some entity (`article`) with some fields (`name`, `description`, `content`). Many users can edit the same article. I want to keep history of the article updates (something like version control) and I want to keep only diffs, not the whole content of the updated article. By the way I use PostgreSQL, but can migrate to any other database.

**UPD**
Open bounty, so here is some requirements. You don't need to fully satisfy them. But if you do it will be much better. Nevertheless any answer is much appreciated. So I want to have an ability:

1. to keep only diffs to not waste my space for no purpose.
2. to fetch any revision (version) of some article. But fetching of the last revision of the article must be really quick. Fetching speed of other revisions is not so important.
3. to fetch any diff (and list of diffs) of some article. Article can have changes in fields: `header`, `description` or `content` (like StackOverflow have changes in header and content), so it must be taken into account.

Comment: OK, so you don't want time travel or some form of audit history because you want to retain only diffs. You'll want to do that at the application level, or (if done in the database) using triggers. I'd be looking into PL/perl, PL/python, etc triggers that can diff contents, personally.

Comment: I would probably store the whole article, and generate the diffs on the fly.

Comment: Actually, I don't have any strong opinion on storing only diffs. But I think storing the every version of article is considerable wasting of disk space. For example: update can contain only some typo fix in an article content. In that case I actually need to store only new version of word, if article is big it would be disaster for disk space. So I think that storing the diffs - the best way. But any other opinion is much appreciated, especially if you have this case before.

Comment: Also, maybe someone knows some ready tools/utilites/modules for my task? In fact I need realize just some sort of version control. And there are a lot of them already realized in the world. Maybe somehow I can bind git to the postgres?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the past, I have used [diff-match-patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) with excellent (and fast) results.  It is available for several languages (my experience with it was in C#).  I did not use it for exactly the process you are describing (we were interested in merging), but it seems to me you could:

1. Save the initial version of an article's text/header/whatever.
2. When a change is made, use diff-match-patch to compute a patch between the newly edited version and what is already in the database.  To get the latest version in the database, simply apply any patches that have already been generated to the original article in order.
3. Save the newly generated patch.

If you wanted to speed things up even more, you could cache the latest version of the article in its own row/table/however-you-organize-things so that getting the latest version is a simple SELECT.  This way, you'd have the initial version, the list of patches, and the current version, giving you some flexibility and speed.

Since you have a set of patches in sequence, fetching any version of the article would simply be a matter of applying patches up to the one desired.

You can [take a look at the patch demo](https://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_patch.html) to see what its patches look like and get an idea of how big they are.

Like I said, I have not used it for exactly this scenario, but diff-match-patch has been designed for doing more or less exactly what you are talking about.  This library is on my short list of software I can use when I have no restrictions on libraries developed out-of-house.

### Update: Some example pseudocode

As an example, you could set up your tables like so (this assumes a few other tables, like Authors):

```
Articles
--------
id
authorId
title
content
timestamp

ArticlePatches
--------------
id
articleId
patchText
timestamp

CurrentArticleContents
----------------------
id
articleId
content
```

Then some basic CRUD could look like:

Insert new article:

```
INSERT INTO Articles (authorId, title, content, timestamp)
  VALUES(@authorId, @title, @content, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO CurrentArticleContents(articleId, content) 
  VALUES(SCOPE_IDENTITY(),@content)
GO
```

Get all articles with latest content for each:

```
SELECT 
  a.id,
  a.authorId,
  a.title,
  cac.content,
  a.timestamp AS originalPubDate
FROM Articles a
INNER JOIN CurrentArticleContents cac 
  ON a.id = cac.articleId
```

Update an article's content:

```
//this would have to be done programatically
currentContent = 
    (SELECT content 
     FROM CurrentArticleContents 
     WHERE articleId = @articleId)

//using the diff-match-patch API
patches = patch_make(currentContent, newContent);
patchText = patch_toText(patches);

//setting @patchText = patchText and @newContent = newContent:
(INSERT INTO ArticlePatches(articleId, patchText, timestamp)
  VALUES(@articleId, @patchText, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO CurrentArticleContents(articleId, content, timestamp)
  VALUES(@articleId, @newContent, GETDATE())
GO)
```

Get the article at a particular point in time:

```
//again, programatically
originalContent = (SELECT content FROM Articles WHERE articleId = @articleId)
patchTexts = 
  (SELECT patchText 
  FROM ArticlePatches 
  WHERE articleId = @articleId
  AND timestamp <= @selectedDate
  ORDER BY timestamp ASCENDING)

content = originalContent
foreach(patchText in patchTexts)
{
  //more diff-match-patch API
  patches = patch_fromText(patchText)
  content = patch_apply(patches, content)[0]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Really helpful! I'll wait for more answers, and if there will be no better ones, mark yours as accepted.

Comment: Just a note. Paul suggests to store full version of original article plus a full version of the latest article to speed up retrieval of the latest version. Depending on the anticipated number of revisions and article size you may consider adding intermediate snapshots of the article to speed up retrieving versions prior to the current. Example: article has 50 revisions. User wants to compare rev 45 vs 48. You have to apply 48 patches to get rev 48. If you store full snapshots for, say, rev 20 and 40, then you need to apply only 8 patches to rev 40 to get rev 48.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov That's definitely a good idea if you anticipate a large number of edits per item and/or frequent access to older revisions of items.  Even so, my guess is that in most use cases, requests for the latest revision of content will outpace requests for older revisions by at least two orders of magnitude.

Comment: @PaulGriffin I think there will be no better answer then yours, so I marked it as accepted. Thanks again for great answer!!! It was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

i have similar issue in workplace.

i implement the use of trigger after update to record all needed data to a another table (which of course you can save only the difference field only), and the new on exist on the real table, while the log live in another table.

Comment: Thanks. I not sure for now where better to perform diff operation in client or in database (I more incline to the client side). But trigger is a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first @PaulGriffin's answer is complete.  And @VladimirBaranov's also got me to thinking about the optimal way to do updates.  I've got a tasty way to handle it in the use case of frequent updates and less frequent reads.  Lazy full record updates.

For example, editing a document online, possibly from different devices.  Optimize for light network traffic and less frequent large db record updates.  Without the ability of the client to go to specific versions (rather than always getting latest).

The database has collection of deltas, indexed by version(could be timestamp), and a lastDocument with lastDocUpdate (version/timestamp).

Frequent use case: Client Edits

- Send only the delta to the Server & update database with delta

Use Case: Client with old document version requests updates

- Send all deltas since current client version

Less Frequent use case: New device, no prior data on client

- On Server, look at lastDocument, apply deltas since lastDocUpdate
- Save updated lastDocument in db, and send to client

The most expensive operation is updating the full document in the database, but it's only done when necessary, ie the client has no version of the document.

That rare action is what actually triggers the full document update.

This setup has no extra db writes, minimal data sent to the client (which updates its' doc with the deltas), and the large text field is updated only when we are already applying the deltas on the server and full document is needed by client.